# LINQ to XML Not Working

Tags: c#, windows, linq-to-xml

I am trying to learn about LINQ and XML files for data storage, while I teach myself C# and VS2010.  I want to read an XML file with a list of server info for some SQL servers that I have in my virtual lab that I use for testing.

My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ServerList>
    <Server>
        <Name>SQLSVR1</Name>
        <Type>Windows Server 2008 R2</Type>
        <Product>Microsoft SQL Server 2008</Product>
        <Database>AspNetDB</Database>
        <UID>Admin</UID>
        <PWD>!Passw0rd</PWD>
    </Server>

    <Server>
        <Name>SQLSVR2</Name>
        <Type>Windows Server 2008 R2</Type>
        <Product>Microsoft SQL Server 2008</Product>
        <Database>AspNetDB</Database>
        <UID>Admin</UID>
        <PWD>!Passw0rd</PWD>
    </Server>
</ServerList>
```

I have a Windows form, which has a ComboBox ("cbSQLServers").  I'd like to populate that ComboBox in the Form_Load() event with the results from the XML file.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = @"..\\..\\ServerList.xml";

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

            var data = from item in xDoc.Descendants("server")
                       select new
                       {
                           serverName = item.Element("Name").Value,
                           serverType = item.Element("Type").Value,
                           serverProduct = item.Element("Product").Value
                       };

            foreach (var p in data)
                cbSQLServers.Items.Add(p.ToString());
            // I used the Console to test if it was doing anything.
            // Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The file " + filePath + " does not exist.");
        }
    }
```

My final goal with this, is that when I run the program and select an item from the ComboBox, it will display the information for that server in a ListBox on the form called LbLog:

```
    private void cbSQLServers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*
         * Pseudo-code...not sure how to pass from Form1_Load() to _SelectedIndexChanged.
            lbLog.Items.Add("Server Name: " + cbSQLServers.SelectedIndex);
            lbLog.Items.Add("\t Type: " + cbSQLServers.SelectedIndex);
            lbLog.Items.Add("\t Product: " + cbSQLServers.SelectedIndex);
            lbLog.Items.Add("\t Database: " + cbSQLServers.SelectedIndex);
            lbLog.Items.Add("\t UID: " + cbSQLServers.SelectedIndex);
            lbLog.Items.Add("\t PWD: " + cbSQLServers.SelectedIndex);
        */
    }
```

Could anyone help me with determining how to read the data from the XML file with LINQ?

Comment: `@"..\\..\\ServerList.xml"` is wrong; use either `@"..\..\ServerList.xml"` or `"..\\..\\ServerList.xml"`, not both.

Comment: Dour, thanks for the catch.  I hadn't realized that I had used both...I think I escaped first and then threw @ in later without removing the escapes.  Oops!  It doesn't affect the output (or lack of it) though ;-(

Comment: Another bit of advice; do not name identifiers `xDoc`, `data`, `item`, `Type` and so on; these do not mean anything. C# is a strongly-typed language, it will tell you what each data type is, you do not need to mangle the names. Identifiers should explain their meaning.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what tags are for.

Comment: Thanks.  First time here, lots of various rules to remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` in your code is an anonymous type, calling `ToString()` on that is probably not going to give you what you want.

If you want to later use individual fields of `cbSQLServers` in `cbSQLServers_SelectedIndexChanged`, you should save the object, not [smash it into a string](http://blog.lexspoon.org/2010/05/stringly-typed-code.html).

Create a class that contains the data in the types you want:

```
public class MyServer
{
    public string Name { get; private set };
    public string OS { get; private set };
    public string Product { get; private set };

    public MyServer(string name, string os, string product)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.OS = os;
        this.Product = product;
    }
}
```

Then save instances of this type:

```
cbSQLServers.DisplayMember = "Name";
foreach (var p in data)
    cbSQLServers.Items.Add(new MyServer(p.servername, p.serverType, p.serverProduct));
```

Then in your handler, you can use individual fields of the selected combobox item:

```
MyServer selectedServer = cbSQLServers.SelectedItem as MyServer;
DoWhateverWith(selectedServer.OS);
```

Comment: Dour High Arch, thank you for the example. I guess we were working on it at the same time, because I read your links and was able to create a class to handle the data: 
    `        private class SelectedServer
            {
                public string serverName, serverType, serverProduct;
    
                public SelectedServer(string name, string type, string product)
                {
                    serverName = name;
                    serverType = type;
                    serverProduct = product;
                }`

Comment: Well I'll be damned...I'm apparently not intelligent enough to figure out how to reply with code... `codetest` works but not an actual code block (even with format spaces).  Oh well.  

Thank you for your advice, and the link to the "stringly-typed" article.  I'm still learning (none of this is covered in my class that I'm taking...just the basics of programming, form controls, and extremely basic OOP).  I appreciate your help and advice!

Answer (score 1):

In your XML the element is called "Server", but in your Linq you reference it as "server".  The case needs to match since both XML and Linq to XML are case-sensitive.

Comment: Mike, Thanks for that!  The output panel displayed the Console output after I made that change.